# Generate access token / token key for Pinterest?

Tags: php, api, model-view-controller, pinterest, pins

Any code example for https://api.pinterest.com/v3/oauth/access_token API.

Followed this [document](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/redoc/pinner_app/#section/User-Authorization/Exchange-the-code-for-an-access-token) but while implementing it, I am getting following error in response.

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "None",
        "oauth_error_code": "invalid_grant"
    },
    "code": 283,
    "data": null,
    "message": "The authorization grant is invalid",
    "endpoint_name": "oauth_access_token",
    "status": "failure"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution. I have added some PHP files and API information on github.

[Click Here to get github Files](https://github.com/sedanijay/pinterest_generate_token_key_apis)

Comment: Hello, a bit unrelated, but how did you manage to create an "App" for your developer account? On their website it says that they are suspended while making some API updates. Thank you!

Comment: @Ícaro I have used old app